# Is there a way to generate a report for the SonarQube branch new code directly and only once?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

What I'm targeting is to run SonarQube analysis on a branch only once, and generate a report for just the new code ( ***like pull requests, the analysis runs one time and displays the result for only the new code***).

What is happening right now when scanning a branch .. the first time analysis is to generate a report for overall code .. and then any other analysis later on is for the new code.

I've tried to use `sonar.newCode.referenceBranch` sonar property .. to analyze my branch according to the reference branch .. so display a report for only the new code but unfortunately it doesn't work as expected .. and I should run analysis again to show the new code result.

Does any one have an idea to achieve this?

Thanks

[image: The screenshot shows what I've got when using sonar reference branch property]

Comment: "...  but unfortunately it doesn't work."  What was the result? Why did it fail?

Comment: [new code](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/new-code-period/) has 4 options: 1) Previous Version 2) Specific analysis 3) Reference Branch 4) Number of days.   3 or 4 seems what you need, but it's unclear why 3 (referencebranch) is not working, or is it because you are running a Community Edition?

Comment: @Luuk it doesn't work as expected .. I was expecting to show a result for only my new added code.
but what I got .. is an analysis for the overall code and I should analyze my code again to get new code analysis

Comment: It is not very logical to only want to see new code errors/improvements, and ignore 'old'/'existing' code error/improvement suggestions.   SonarQube tries (help you) to improve the quality of your code, and that would not help when you ignore history.

Comment: Agree with you .. but then what's the benefit from referenceBranch property ?

Comment: I thought that it would analyze your code (new code) against the reference branch (old existing analysis)